# form内のdivのデータを送る方法はありますか？

Tags: html, laravel

`form method = post` 内のdivのデータを送る方法はありますか？
以下Laravelのコードです。

`div id = "tetsuya"` を送りたいのですが良い方法はありませんか？
hidden使って入れ込むしかありませんか？

```
<form method="post" action={{ route('output')}}>
    @csrf   
    <input type="text" id = "komuro" name="kei" value =""> 
    <div id="tetsuya">63</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`formdata` イベントを使うと簡単です。

```js
form.addEventListener('formdata' e => {
  e.formData.append('mitsuko', document.querySelector('#tetsuya').textContent);
});
```